# Some types of 301 redirects working, some are not

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I normally do redirects in htaccess as below:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^pages/whyinstallr\.htm$ /why-install/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

On a certain site these types of redirects are not working, however I can redirect using the simple method below:

```
Redirect 301 /pages/whyinstallr.htm http://www.example.com/why-install/
```

Is there an obvious reason why the first type of redirects are not working, perhaps a setting on the hosting or similar? The site is on wordpress, but I have used the first type of redirects on many, many wordpress site in the past with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was the order of entries in .htaccess.  I needed to add the redirects before the default WordPress entries, not after as i was trying before:

i.e:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^pages/whyinstallr\.htm$ /why-install/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```